# VBA code to send personalized email from excel

Tags: vba, email, excel

I would like to have a code that will send emails using excel table as source. email addresses are in the table, however they are duplicates.

I found a code that generates and email for every row/line, but i need it to generate an email for multiple rows that contain same email address.

**PLEASE!** Modify the code so that it will generate only **1** email from multiple rows that contain same email address.
*I would do it myself but i do not know how because i do not know how to code in VBA.

The code i have so far is and it generates email for EVERY line, which is not what i am looking for:

```
Sub email()
Dim i As Long
Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim strto, strcc, strbcc, strsub, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

For i = 1 To Range("c65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strto = Cells(i, 8)
    strsub = "Missing Books"
    strbody = "Good day," & vbNewLine & _
        "We are missing below books:" & vbNewLine & _
        Cells(i, 1) & Chr(32) & Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 6) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "brgds," & vbNewLine & _
        "Alex"

    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
        '.Send
        .display

    End With
    On Error Resume Next

Next

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The final email for email address should look like this:

> to: test@email.com
>   subject: Report!
>      Hello!
>
> Here is the overview of the used service:
>
> Period / Number / Company/ Count / Duration * *header row*
>   201504 / 900654 / ETV / 5 / 89 / * *data row, includes email in column H*
>   201504 / 900098 / ETV / 2 / 24 / * *data row, includes email in column
>   H*
>
> Best wishes,    Annu

NOTE: First row is the header row and starting from second row are the data cells. They come from a table as does the emails
NOTE: H is the Column for emails - there can be 10 times/lines test@email.com and it needs only 1 email but with the information that comes prior the email cell itself.

Edit*
[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C6eu.png)

Comment: can you show an extract of the sheet containing the data please

Comment: every row contains only 1 email?

Comment: I added a link to an original post(i hope it works). Yes every row has only 1  email address but there are like multiple rows with the same email address.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/7C6eu.png

Answer (score 1):

Please see below to make a string with each row in a column, code will neglect repeating data, then you can use that string in your mailto variable:

[image]

```
Sub uniqueSTR()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim mailSTR As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Your workbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Your sheet name

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To lastRow
    If InStr(mailSTR, Range("A" & i).Value) = 0 Then
        If mailSTR = "" Then
            mailSTR = Range("A" & i).Value
        Else
            mailSTR = mailSTR & ";" & Range("A" & i).Value '<- Mail seperator is ";"
        End If
    End If
Next

Range("B1").Value = mailSTR '<- Your result

End Sub
```

Comment: Not what i was looking for. However I wonder if it could be used horizontally not vertically, as I understand is done in this code.

Comment: ok, i think now i understood. Sorry for jumping to conclusion directly. I will try to update the code accordingly.